# microk8s.ctr image import error import image

Tags: docker, microk8s, multipass

someone has tried microk8s on windows (I only have to use it for a process I always use debian) I have an error when importing an image to microk8s

command:
`microk8s ctr image import image.tar`

reply:
ctr: open image.tar: no such file or directory
An error occurred when trying to execute 'sudo microk8s.ctr image import image.tar' with 'multipass': returned exit code 1.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem!

Answer (score 7):

The `microk8s.ctr ...` command is being executed inside the VM managed by multipass, so it cannot access files from the host.

In order to import it, the image must be first transfered from host system to the VM.

```
multipass transfer image.tar microk8s-vm:/tmp/image.tar
```

Only then import

```
microk8s ctr image import /tmp/image.tar
```